# cannot be cast to java.base/java.util.Optional

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to implement users authentication using Spring and Angular. I tried this:

```
    @PostMapping("request")
    public ResponseEntity<?> resetRequest(@RequestBody PasswordResetDTO resetDTO) {
        return userRepository.findByUsername(resetDTO.getName()).map(user -> {

            if (!user.getEmail().equals(resetDTO.getEmail())) {
                return new ResponseEntity<>("NAME_AND_EMAIL_MISMATCH", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            }

            resetHandler.sendResetMail(user);

            return ok(resetDTO);
        })
                .orElseGet(() -> notFound().build());
    }
```

**Interface:**

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<Users, Integer> {
    Optional<Users> findByUsername(String username);

    Optional<Users> findByEmail(String email);

    Optional<Users> findByResetCode(String code);
}
```

**Impl:**

```
    @Override
    public Optional<Users> findByUsername(String username) {
        String hql = "select e from " + Users.class.getName() + " e where e.login = ?";
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery(hql).setParameter(0, username);
        Optional<Users> users = (Optional<Users>) query.getSingleResult();
        return users;
    }
```

But I get `Users cannot be cast to java.base/java.util.Optional`

What is the proper way to implement this? Should I use Optional or I should use just null check?

Comment: Query.getSingleResult() never, ever returns an Optional. Either it returns the Users instance, or it throws an exception. Read the api doc. And don't use a raw Query? use a TypedQuery. That will allow your code to be type-safe.

Comment: Can you show me working example, please?

Comment: How about reading the api doc first and trying finding this out by yourself? Beware: you might learn things.

Comment: Your should also read the documentation of spring data jpa, because you're writing code that doesn't need to be written. The interface is sufficient. The implementation is unnecessary.

Comment: Sure but let me see what is the proposed solution.

Comment: The point of Spring Data JPA, which is what makes it so easy and useful, is that you only need to define the interface. It will generate the implementation of the interface automatically, when you run the program. So, throw away your implementation of the repository interface, and it will work fine.

Comment: @Jesper The problem is that I need to put some additional verification logic. Can you give me some advice how to implement this functionality properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First as JB Nizet suggested, use typed query. Second use `getResultList` if you are not sure if the DB will always have a record for your query (since you use optional you probably dont).

Here is updated `findByUsername`:

```
@Override
public Optional<Users> findByUsername(String username) {
    String hql = "select e from " + Users.class.getName() + " e where e.login = ?";
    TypedQuery<Users> query = entityManager.createQuery(hql, Users.class).setParameter(0, username);
    List<Users> users = query.getResultList();
    return users.isEmpty() ? Optional.empty() : Optional.of( users.get(0) );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  public Optional<User> editUser(int id) {
    
  return userRepository.findById(id);
}

@RequestMapping("/edit-user")
public String editUser(@RequestParam int id, HttpServletRequest request) {
     Optional<User> user = userService.editUser(id);
     System.out.println("user = "+user);
     request.setAttribute("users", user);
     request.setAttribute("mode", "MODE_UPDATE");         
    return "welcomepage";
}
```